# Align the columns of table to right and left

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am using the table in my application. I have two columns in the table which I need to use for next and previous buttons. I want to keep them in the right corner and left corner. How I can do that?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <a href="#Previous" style="float:left;color:#fff">
        < Back </a>
          <img src="images/icon-previous.png" />
    </td>
    <td style="float:right;margin-left: 208px;">
      <a data-bind="click:$root.Next" style="float:right">
        <img src="images/icon-next.png" />
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is a different version. There are three images. I need to align them as left, center, and right orders using table. Is it possible?

```
<footer data-role="footer">
  <div style="width:100%">
    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left">
          <img src="images/icon-add1.png" /></a>

          </div>
          </div>

        </td>

        <td style="text-align:center">
          <a><img src="images/icon-add2.png" /></a>
        </td>

        <td style="text-align:right">
          <img src="images/icon-add3.png" /></a>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
</footer>
```

[image]

Comment: The HTML is the last part is not [well-formed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_element) (e.g., missing start tags for `</div>` and `</a>`). That would be the first thing to fix.

Comment: OK, the OP has left the building: *"Last seen more than 5 years ago"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, please fix the HTML errors in your examples in the question, and read on.

You can set `text-align: right;` on the second table cell. However it's recommend to avoid using table for layout, an example of using div with flexbox below.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

td:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a>&lt; Back</a></td>
    <td><a>Next &gt;</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<hr>

<div>
  <a>&lt; Back</a>
  <a>Next &gt;</a>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

See the follow example for making a 3-column layout.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed; /* NEW */
}

td:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: center; /* NEW */
}

td:nth-child(3) {
  text-align: right;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a>&lt; Back</a></td>
    <td><a>Middle</a></td>
    <td><a>Next &gt;</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<hr>

<div>
  <a>&lt; Back</a>
  <a>Middle</a>
  <a>Next &gt;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your source code: the less-than mark should be an HTML entity. Additionally you'd better put your buttons in TH elements so CSS will not affect other rows with TD elements. Look at this example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
th {
border:1px solid black;
width:500px;
}
th:nth-child(1)
{
text-align:left;
}
th:nth-child(2)
{
text-align:right;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<th>
<a href="#Previous"> &lt; Back </a>
<img src="images/icon-previous.png" />
</th>
<th>
<img src="images/icon-next.png" />
<a href="#next">  Next &gt;</a>
</th>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it directly in your tag as:

```
<td align="right">
```

Or you can also try this using CSS:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><a href="#">Item 1</a></th>
    <th><a href="#">Item 2</a></th>
    <th><a href="#">Item 3</a></th>
    <th class="right"><a href="#">Item 4</a></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

##### CSS

```
table { width: 100%; }
th { float: left; }
th.right { float: right; }​
```

Comment: It is not recommended to use attributes for styling, use CSS, and also, don't crash a table with `float` if you really doesn't need to

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```css
table {

      border:1px solid #000;
   width: 100%;
}

img {
     width: 20px;
     vertical-align: middle;
}

.left {
 float: left;
}

.right {
 float: right;
}

a {
       text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
   <td class="pre">
  <a href="#" class="left"> Previous
   <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT6zvVdVIJsJrw6WZFUCNqDAuIG_DTGToOuBiqXEK3bwDEnYEqPwEraqpNd" />
 </a>
   </td>
   <td>
  <a href="#"  class="right">
 <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSWdR49Yc8BQgJ5Wx2re6xg43bccDAwWpVdJxSf_8-9WAlIM577tjup6kzU" /> Next
  </a>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```